# De sitter spacetime and co-ordinates

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

I was recently looking at de - Sitter spacetime and I relaized that there are many different parameterizations possible, each of which has it's own advantages.

Can someone help me out and list the most common co-ordinate systems used to describe de - Sitter spacetime and what is exactly the advantage of using that particular co-ordinate patch.

Also, the de sitter space describes for us an expanding universe with positive cosmological constant, but we can write a static co-ordinate patch. Is the static co-ordinates like a co-moving patch with the expanding universe s.t the metric components are independent of time?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2363,
http://www.ru.nl/publish/pages/760966/thesis_chris_ripken.pdf

Comment: It will be helpful if you can answer the question in a short qualitative format

Comment: @Tushar Gopalka --Vilenkin has remarked that contraction precedes expansion in de Sitter space, which I believe means that anti-de Sitter space precedes de Sitter space in whatever cosmological models might contain both.  Anything "independent of time" might not work too well in models based on General Relativity, although Nikodem J. Poplawski has written numerous papers, found by his name on Arxiv, that use causal separation to describe models based on the more recent Einstein-Cartan-Sciama-Kibble ("ECSK") theory.

Comment: At https://www.tsijournals.com/articles/on-de-sitter-universe.pdf , there is a paper that relates "contraction of time" with "expansion of space", & vice-versa, in a de Sitter universe, although I don't know what relativistic theory it might rely on.